# Not able to undelete Attachments

Tags: sandbox, sobject, standard-objects

I have written a trigger on Attachment. Events are after insert, update, delete and undelete. But I noticed that the undelete trigger doesn't fire at all. I tried to undelete from recycle bin. Even there I am prompted error. I haven't undeleted yet. I am of system admin profile.

[image: Error on undelete]

Comment: and are any of the 4 conditions true in your use case?

Answer (score 3):

The problem you're likely having is that an Attachment is really a child of a Parent Object Record. Without that reference, you won't be able to find or restore it.